# Searchable Profile fields do not work

Tags: custom-fields, profile, permissions, forms

I have an issue on creating profiles.

When I create a profile with several fields such as "First Name" "Past Name" "E-Mail" and some Custom Fields and I set these fields to "searchable", everything looks fine at first. I can check the preview and the Use - Create/Edit/Listing Modes and it works.

But after a while, it suddenly doesn't work any more:

- I get for the Listing Mode the error message: "No fields in this Profile have been configured as searchable. Ask the site administrator to check the Profile setup. "
- Preview is empty
- Preview od searchable fields tell: "Profile Field Preview This CiviCRM profile field is view only." -> BUT IT IS DEFINITELY SEARCHABLE AND NOT "VIEW ONLY"

for me this feels a bit like a bug. Would be nice to hear if this problem is known and if there is any fix

Comment: Do you have 'Standalone Form or Directory' enabled for the profile? Does it work after CiviCRM cache clear?

Comment: Yes, standalone is activated. As I said: At first, it was working fine. Only after a while without changing anything, it suddenly produced errors.
Therefore, I will check your cache-suggestion, it sounds plausible.

Comment: Ok this is weird. It works now. It did nothing since yesterday. If the problem returns, I will try clearing the cache. I seems reasonable, that this is some kind of cache problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clearing the Cach solves the issue to about 90%. I still have problems (I granted edit-permission to a role but it only gets the view-option, despite I enabled edit in the profile, in the ACL and in the Role-permissions). Probably these things will solve out over night again.
Anyways, thanks a lot, we are a big step further.

Comment: After some time, I can say that I still have the same problem and clearing the cache doesn't necessarily solve the issue.

Comment: Where would you put the dbCache parameters?
I am just new at setting it up and cant find where to put it

Answer (score 1):

Clearing cache may be the solution? If yes you can turn on 'Clean-up Temporary Data and Files' schedule job with below parameter.

```
dbCache=1
memCache=1
```